# Complete Internet Repair Tool and command prompt

Tags: networking, internet

I downloaded *Complete Internet Repair Tool* by **Rizonesoft**.

And most of time, the tool is helpful for resolving no Internet issue.

While executing the app, it looks like

[image]

And I check boxes shown in the snaps.

Without using any third party software, I am looking for alternatives so that I can

1. Reset TCP/IP,
2. Repair Winsock,
3. Renew Internet Connections
4. Flush DNS Resolver Cache
5. Repair SSL/ HTTPS/ Cryptography
6. Restore the default hosts file

Can I perform all above tasks using command prompt?

If yes, please let me know.

Regards
John

Answer (score 1):

#### Can I perform all below tasks using command prompt?

> 1. Reset TCP/IP,

```
netsh int ip reset reset.log
```

> 2. Repair Winsock,

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
```

Note: A reboot is required.

> 3. Renew Internet Connections

```
ipconfig /registerdns
route /f
```

Note: A reboot is required.

> 4. Flush DNS Resolver Cache

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

> 5. Repair SSL/ HTTPS/ Cryptography

This part is too broad.

> 6. Restore the default hosts file

Not easily done from the command line See [How to reset the Hosts file back to the default](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/972034/how-to-reset-the-hosts-file-back-to-the-default) for instructions.